# issue about Paying with Walmart Debit VISA card to Paypal

Tags: paypal

I have integrated Paypal in my site. The background is using Paypal express checkout. 
The problem I'm facing is that when I paying with Walmart Debit VISA card, the Paypal service response Success BUT the the money is not decreased in Walmart Debit VISA card and also my Paypal merchant account didn't get money. What's the issue here could be?

Comment: With no code snippets that you might suspect, it might be corrupt bankers for all we know. Either post some code or try asking PayPal support for further details of the failed transaction instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you calling DoExpressCheckoutPayment, and are you pointing to the Live API endpoint(s)?
(https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp instead of https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp).

Since you mention "The PayPal service responds Success"  I assume you're looking at ACK=Success. This is merely an acknowledgement that the API call was processed successfully; for the transaction state I'd recommend looking at PAYMENTSTATUS=Completed. This is returned in the DoExpressCheckoutPayment API response.